# morrisjs line graph not showing the first xLabel

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I don't know what I'm missing here.
The line chart isn't showing the first x label:

[image: charterror]

Here is my code:

```
new Morris.Line({
element: 'chart_170',
data: [
    { y: '2015-04-10 04:01', a: -10},
    { y: '2015-04-10 10:45', a: -10},
    { y: '2015-04-11 05:45', a: -10},
    { y: '2015-04-12 05:45', a: -8},
    { y: '2015-04-12 03:45', a: -8}],
resize: true,
xkey: ['y'],
ykeys: 'a',
labels: 'a',
xLabels: ['day'],
ymax: 'auto',
resize: 'true',
hideHover: true,
yLabelFormat: function(y) {
    if (y % 1 === 0) 
        return -y;
    else return '';
}});
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could get it to show up by adding an event at April 9, 23:39 (11 PM) and setting the event stroke to 0. Basically, if the center of the label format would lie before the earliest data point on the graph, it won't be drawn.

I also noticed that, in your fiddle, you didn't wrap your `labels` option with brackets, which would cause weird behavior if your string were longer than one character.

```
new Morris.Line({
    element: 'chart_170',
    data: [
        { y: '2015-04-10 04:01', a: -10},
        { y: '2015-04-10 10:45', a: -10},
        { y: '2015-04-11 05:45', a: -10},
        { y: '2015-04-12 05:45', a: -8},
        { y: '2015-04-12 03:45', a: -8}],
    events: ['2015-04-09 23:39'],
    eventStrokeWidth: 0,
    resize: true,
    xkey: ['y'],
    ykeys: ['a'],
    labels: ['a'],
    xLabels: ['day'],
    xLabelFormat: function(x) { 
        return x.toDateString();
    },
    ymax: 'auto',
    resize: 'true',
    hideHover: true,
    yLabelFormat: function(y) {
        if (y % 1 === 0) 
            return -y;
        else return '';
    }
});
```

[Try it in a fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/8rp4uzxo/2/).